# How to globally style dynamic react data (dangerouslySetInnerHTML) with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

Considering we have this component:

```js
const Policy = ({ policy }) => (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: policy } }></div>
)
export default Policy
```

And some others like these (for every scenario, `h1`, `h2`, etc.):

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const H1 = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;
```

What would be the proper way to **centralize** the heading styles maintenance?

Options thought:

- Separate and import the same CSS for both/etc, one global and one scoped;
- Convert our backend HTML data to our React/HTML somehow ([html-to-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react));
- Inject the CSS styles only to this Policy component
- Other idea

I'm thinking in having this style available to any `h1`, `h2`, etc. but I don't know if I'm thinking wrong and should get rid of this old pattern for any reason.

The main discussion here is **what's the best way to centralize, style and deal with dynamic html data for react nowadays**.

**Update**: maybe [`createGlobalStyle`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) would be a good option for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, you have several options that are mostly **personal** preference.

1. Style globally in the `head` using the `createGlobalStyle` function. The advantage of this approach is that it's not render blocking and can be easily scoped using a `className`. The disadvantage is that it's always in the `head`.
2. Use modular css and locally scope the component. The advantages are that if you're using Webpack, then you can lazy import the component module and therefore only require the stylesheet when needed, and it gives you the option to target `:global`s if needed. The disadvantage is that its render blocking (in addition, it stays in the `head` once downloaded, however, since its locally scoped, it shouldn't interfere with other styles) and it can't select static child class names.
3. Conditionally add a stylesheet in the `head` using `react-helmet`. The advantage of this approach is that it's only in the `head` when needed. The disadvantage is that it can cause UI flashing (because it has be loaded within the `render` method/`return` statement), has to make the API call to fetch the stylesheet for each (re)mount, and is not very reusable because it adds the stylesheet for each component instance.

So, I'd recommend going with option 1. That said, if I'm working with large stylesheet(s), then option 2 -- even with its selector limitations. On that note, I generally try not to store stringified HTML, unless absolutely necessary. When dealing with databases, large strings can be slow to retrieve and, depending on the user's device, even slower to display. In addition, using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` opens you up to [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). In fact, I'm in the process of making a [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) editor that utilizes plain text and transforms it into HTML on-the-fly. Perhaps that's an option worth considering  -- it also handles HTML, although again, opens up XSS vulnerabilities.

**Working demo of all 3 options**:

[Demo](https://yebq2.csb.app/)

[image: Edit Stylesheets]

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
const Policy = ({ className, policy }) => (
    <div className={className} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: policy }}></div>
)

const StyledPolicy = styled(Policy)`
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: palevioletred;
  }

  h2 {
    ...
  }
`;

export default StyledPolicy
```

Then you don't need to globally scope the CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I know how to do that, that's the third option "Inject styles only to the component". I'm looking forward to a more global approach or at least discuss about it, if it a global approach is still valid or not, if converting dynamic data to react is a good option or not, etc.